# How to set auto shutdown in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

Can I set auto shutdown in Windows 10 without using any applications?

I want to shutdown my computer after X minutes. Should I install any applications for that?

P.S. Sorry, I'm a new here.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: Thanks for advice. I didn't hear about SuperUser. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Command Promp and type

```
shutdown –s –t X
```

where `X` means number of seconds e.g. 10 minutes = 600 seconds

Comment: Wav thanks, it works but what does mean -s and -t?

Comment: Did you try to use Google? `-s` : Shuts down the local computer and `-t   xx`   : Sets the timer for system shutdown in xx seconds. The default is 20 seconds. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry but I can't give an upvote because my reputation

Comment: Your welcome. never mind and try to use google before asking here

Comment: Ok, I will. Sorry for that. This is my first question :)

Comment: Hello @Megatron, Now I can give an upvote. So as I promised +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create a batch file with "shutdown /f" and apply it to a Scheduled Task.

Comment: I will try it also but the answer from megatron is working well

Comment: No need, MegaTron's answer is better then mine, skips an extra step.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't give an upvote because my reputation

Comment: Not to worry, just mark MegaTron's answer correct, as his is the best answer here.

Comment: Thank you. You are a good person. I'll accept that answer and maybe give you upvote later

Comment: Hello @level42, Now I can give an upvote. So as I promised +1 for you

Comment: Thanks for that :) Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut with the following command:

shutdown /s /t 1000 (Replace 1000 with time in seconds), and save to Desktop/wherever.

Comment: Thanks but your answer is the same as megatron's one

Comment: It just depends whether you want to go to cmd prompt or just click on the shortcut - it is however a different way of doing the same thing.